# Service worker in Safari

Tags: angular, safari, service-worker

I have a major problem with service workers, or what I think is a service worker related problem. The problem I have (only in Safari) both on Mac and iOS is that every second time I visit a route I got a 504 (Gateway Timeout) message in the console and no data is fetched from the server.

Thanks in advance,

Mattias

Comment: I have the very same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Anyone got fix of this?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling `etag` from server side fixed my issue.

Comment: But what's the reason behind this, any clue? also is there any drawback of implementing this?

Comment: working fine, But If I want to use ETag too? What will be the solution in that case?

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, and I was able to fix this by delaying the API call (in a component) to be executed 300 milliseconds after the page reload. So my code looks like the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(this._sendRequest.bind(this), 300);
}
```